# Fortran: Whole array operations in Fixed Form Source

Tags: module, segmentation-fault, fortran

I am getting "Segmentation Fault" error over and over again, while using my subroutines (I have put all of them in MODULEs) with a code written in Fixed Form Source (during fortran77 days).

The original make file (Linux platform) is a mess, it compiles only ".f" source, so I had to change the extensions of my files from ".f90" to ".f", and have left first 7 columns blank in my modules.
My modules extensively use whole array operations and operations on array-sections, and I declare the variables in F90 style, many of them are assumed-size arrays.

**My question:-** although the compiler compiles these modules (having whole-array/array-section operations) without any warning/error, however is this "segmentation fault" due to the usage of modules with whole-array/array-section operations (kept in .f files) in a legacy code?

For example I have written following code in "algebra.f" module:

```
    function dyad_vv(v1,v2)     !dyadic product of two vectors
    real*8, dimension(:)::v1,v2
    real*8, dimension(size(v1,1),size(v2,1))::dyad_vv
    integer i,j
    do i=1,size(v1,1)
    do j=1,size(v2,1)
    dyad_vv(i,j)=v1(i)*v2(j)
    end do 
    end do
    end function
    !==================================        
    function dot_mv(m,v)   !dot product of a matrix and a vector
    real*8, dimension(:,:)::m
    real*8, dimension(:)::v
    real*8, dimension(size(m,1))::dot_mv
    integer i,j
    do i=1,size(m,1)
    dot_mv(i)=0.0000D0
    do j=1,size(v,1)
    dot_mv(i)=dot_mv(i)+m(i,j)*v(j)
    end do 
    end do        
    end function
    !==================================        
    function dot_vm(v,m)  !dot product of a vector and a matrix
    real*8, dimension(:)::v
    real*8, dimension(:,:)::m
    real*8, dimension(size(m,2))::dot_vm
    integer i,j
    do i=1,size(m,2)
    dot_vm(i)=0.0000D0
    do j=1,size(v,1)
    dot_vm(i)=dot_vm(i)+v(j)*m(j,i)
    end do 
    end do                
    end function
```

Comment: What are you thinking of ?  Why are you degrading your code from Fortran 90 to FORTRAN77 ?  Most of us, when given the necessity of harmonising old and new codes, take the opportunity to upgrade from 77 to 90.  Furthermore your `dot_product` routines seem to be redundant, replaceable by the intrinsic `matmul`. As to your question, segmentation faults in Fortran programs generally arise from either (a) attempting to access an array element outside the array bounds, or (b) mismatching procedure actual arguments and dummy arguments.  Either of these seems very likely with the code mess you have.

Comment: Your arguments are _assumed-shape_ arrays and not assumed-size arrays. These require explicit interfaces in the calling routines. Do you by "module" understand Fortran 90 `MODULE`s that you then `USE` in the calling routines or simply "compilation modules/units", also known as "source files"?

Comment: @HristoIliev: thanks for correcting me about array names. I am using the fortran modules, the file starts with 
--
`module module_name`
---
and I put the following statement is my subroutines:
`use module_name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand a little on my already over-long comment:

Segmentation faults in Fortran programs generally arise from either (a) attempting to access an array element outside the array bounds, or (b) mismatching procedure actual arguments and dummy arguments.

Fortunately, intelligent use of your compiler can help you spot both these situations.  For (a) you need to switch on run-time array bounds checking, and for (b) you need to switch on compile-time subroutine interface checking.  Your compiler manual will tell you what flags you need to set.

One of the advantages of modern Fortran, in particular of `modules` is that you get procedure interface checking *for free* as it were, the compiler takes care, at compile time, of checking that dummy and actual arguments match.

So I don't think your problem stems directly from writing modern Fortran in fixed-source form.  But I do think that writing modern Fortran in fixed-source form to avoid re-writing your makefile and to avoid upgrading some FORTRAN77 is a sufficiently perverse activity that you will find it painful in the short run, and regret it in the long run as you continue to develop degraded code.

Face up to it, refactor now.

Comment: +1 The first thing I would do is turn on run-time bounds checking.

Comment: @High-Performance-Mark : Thank you for the detailed reply about the problem.